# password_change_done not using custom template in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

I used Django's *auth_views.password_change* to allow a user to change their password. It uses a custom template and it works well, but the problem I'm having is that it redirects to Django's *password change successful* admin template instead of the custom template I declared.

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

from . import views

app_name = 'users'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^add-user/$', views.CreateUserView.as_view(), name='add-user'),
    url(r'^search/$', views.UserSearchView.as_view(), name='search-users'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/settings/update$', views.UpdateAccountView.as_view(), name='update-account'),
    url(r'^settings/change/$', auth_views.password_change, {'template_name': 'users/forms/change-password.html'},
    name='change-password'),
    url(r'^settings/change-done/$', auth_views.password_change_done,
    {'template_name': 'users/forms/change-password-done.html'}, name='change-password-done'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/delete-user/$', views.DeleteUserView.as_view(), name='delete-user'),
```

Any Ideas what I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

`url(r'^settings/change/$', auth_views.password_change, {'template_name': 'users/forms/change-password.html',post_change_redirect:'change-password-done'},name='change-password'),`

Without `post_change_redirect` default template will be loaded in that case.

Comment: Do I place that in my change-password url as a parameter?

Comment: I did that but now I have a TypeError: url() got multiple values for argument 'name'

Comment: @nastyn8: sorry again, please see the update. I'm writing on the run so please check the syntax. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

In `INSTALLED_APPS` ensure that your app with the custom templates is specified before `admin`.

Django searches for the template in order.

Answer (score 0):

Quite long since this question was asked, but the above answers didn't work for me and this did. In `urls.py`:

Make sure this import is there:

`from django.contrib.auth.views import ..., password_change_done, ...`

Then remove `url(r'^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))` from the URLs and override the `password_change_done` view with your custom template. Again, I also had the above suggestions already implemented in my code.